# need help critiquing my idea on how to automate an email reminder system

Tags: email, grails

I am working on a performance review tool using a `grails` project written in `groovy` and I need to do the following

One week after someone's performance review has been created and it has not been completed, send an email reminder to that person.

For a solution, (this is the best idea I could come up with) I could write a function, that would check the `dateCreated` field for each performance review and determine if one week has gone by. If so, generate an email. Then, I could use a cron job to run that function once a day.

I'm pretty sure this is possible from what I've read but I've never worked with scripts or cron jobs before. Any feedback would be mucho appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at  [Quartz grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz)